# finding text sibling in selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

```
<table class="questionKeyHeader">
   <tbody>
      <tr valign="top">
         <td>
            <a>A0310C</a> = 0<br>
            <a>A2300</a> = 05/17/2018<br>
            <a>A2400B</a> = 05/12/2018<br>
            <a>A2400C</a> = --/--/----<br>
            <a>H0200C</a> = Blank/Skipped<br>
            <a>H0500</a> = 0<br>
            <a>O0100E2</a> = 0<br>
            <a>O0100F2</a> = 0<br>
            <a>O0100M2</a> = 0<br>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Above is the HTML this Selenium test is trying to parse. The goal is to find the text that comes after the  element.  The following xpath will find a given  element:

```
.//following::table[@class="questionKeyHeader"]//td/a[text()="A2300"]
```

But it fails when appending /following-sibling::text() to the end of it.  What is the trick to get at the text between the < a > and < br >?

Comment: If I were you, I would make a for loop thats going to take both parameters and put them together by str(a) + str(br) , I know its not effective, but still better not effective way than none :)

Comment: If you need to only get the text, you should consider using `regex`

Comment: @Gsk , do not use `regex` to parse HTML - there are a lot of tools more appropriate for this task. Current issue can be solved with JavaScript executor. OP needs to specify which programming language he uses

Comment: @SamCarleton Which _Selenium Language Binding Art_ are you using? _Java_ / _Python_ / _C#_ / _NodeJS_ ?

Answer (score 0):

It's messy, but it should work as expected :

```
substring-after(substring-before(normalize-space(//td),normalize-space(//a[3]/text())),//a[2]/text())
```

Comment: Thank you, we opted to grab ALL the text from the table and parse it manually, than we consulted the person that wrote the test case and learned that we where looking at the wrong table!